# webpack 3 sass-loader can't import scss files without relative path

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, sass-loader

I'm using `webpack 3.10.0` in a React project started with `create-react-app`.  I'm trying to adjust my Webpack configuration so that I can import scss files without relative paths.

For example `@import ../../scss_variables/vars.scss` works perfectly fine in `myComponent.module.scss` but I'd like to be able to simply use `@import scss_variables/vars.scss`.  I thought the following configuration would do the trick but after many attempts I haven't been able to get the `@import` to work.  I'm getting the following error:

```
Module build failed:
@import "scss_variables/vars.scss";
^
File to import not found or unreadable: scss_variables/vars.scss.
in /path/to/app/src/components/myComponent/myComponent.module.scss (line 1, column 1)
```

File Structure:

```
app
-- config
---- webpack.config.dev.js
---- paths.js
-- src
---- components
------ myComponent
-------- myComponent.jsx
-------- myComponent.module.scss
---- scss_variables
------ vars.scss
```

`webpack.config.dev.js`:

```
  const paths = require('./paths');

  {
      test: /\.module\.scss/,
      use: [
          require.resolve('style-loader'),
          {
              loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
              options: {
                  importLoaders: 1,
                  modules: true,
                  localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
                  includePaths: [paths.appSrc]
              },
          },
          'sass-loader'
      ]
  },
  {
      test: /^((?!\.module).)*\.scss/,
      use: [
          require.resolve('style-loader'),
          {
              loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
              options: {
                  importLoaders: 1,
                  includePaths: [paths.appSrc]
              },
          },
          'sass-loader'
      ]
  },
```

`paths.js`:

```
const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
const resolveApp = relativePath => path.resolve(appDirectory, relativePath);
module.exports = { appSrc: resolveApp('src') };
```

Comment: Use webpack `resolve` to set an alias for the root path of your scss files.

Comment: so something like this?

    resolve: {
      alias: {
        scss_variables$: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scss_variables')
      }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Use Webpack's [`resolve.alias`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias) configuration property to define a shortcut location for importing.

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      scss_variables: path.resolve(__dirname, '../scss_variables/')
    }
  }
};
```

Now `@import ../../scss_variables/vars.scss` can be written as `@import scss_variables/vars.scss`.

---

**Edit**

Use this in your config in place of what you have:

```
{
  test: /\.module\.scss/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        importLoaders: 1,
        modules: true,
        localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
        includePaths: [paths.appSrc]
      },
    },
    'sass-loader'
  ]
},
{
  test: /(?<!\.module)\.scss$/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        importLoaders: 1,
        includePaths: [paths.appSrc]
      },
    },
    'sass-loader'
  ]
}
```

It looks like the regex test you had for `.scss` files without the preceding `.module` part was incorrect.

Comment: Still getting the same `Module build failed` error.  Any thoughts on what could be going on?   NOTE:  the file structure I had originally written out was slightly off.  `scss_variables` lives under `src`.  I've corrected it above.

Comment: I'm assuming you corrected the paths and it still didn't work?

Comment: It may be that your webpack.config.js is invalid. For your second `.scss` rule, what files are you trying to test for? Files ending in `.scss` but not `.module.scss`?

Comment: I believe that's what that means.  This webpack config comes straight out of `create-react-app`.   I'm not very well versed with webpack.  Should `resolve.alias` work with scss files/sass-loader?  All the examples in the documentation deal with JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, `resolve.alias` works with Sass. I updated my answer with more info.

Comment: Thanks @Adam, much appreciated.  I'm guessing I can remove `includePaths: [paths.appSrc]` now since that was from my initial attempt.

Comment: Try removing all `options` from both rules.